# Evaluating overfitting in a logistic regression model

Tags: logistic-regression, overfitting, model-evaluations

I have developed a logistic regression model for a classification problem and obtained an AUC (Area Under the Curve) score of approximately 0.9. The model was estimated by splitting the available data using the common 70-30 rule (70% training data, 30% testing data).

Now, I would like to understand if my model is indeed overfitting the training data. In particular, I'm interested in understanding whether or not the good achieved model performance (e.g., ROC-AUC score ~0.9) is due to overfitting.

Could someon guide me on how to evaluate the presence of overfitting in my logistic regression model given these circumstances, please? I thought about applying my model on the testing data to obtain model-implied estimates but such approach would not lead anywhere since the real-world observations of my target variable are not available yet and won't be in the near future.

Any suggestions is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the original train set, or at least a train set similar to the original?

Answer (score 1):

Just [cross-validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) your model. Basically, you keep apart a portion of the training data (now called the validation data or split) which are then used for validation (same as testing but on such validation split).

There are various cross-validation methods, like the [leave-one-out](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html) or the [k-fold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) cross-validation.

In practice you can use the [cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) function from `scikit-learn`:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

# this would perform (stratified) 5-fold cross-validation on ROC-AUC metric
scores = cross_validate(estimator=LogisticRegression(...), X=x_train, y=y_train,
                        cv=5, scoring='roc_auc', 
                        return_train_score=True, return_estimator=True)
```

And then compare the `scores['train_score']` with the `scores['test_score']`, if the gap is large the model is likely overfitting: you get a score for each cross-val fold, so you can plot and/or aggregate them for example.

If you haven't used `scikit-learn` to train your logistic regression model you can still set-up the validation procedure manually.